# Link component tag in HTML to a component passed in constructor

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am fairly new to Angular and TypeScript in general.

In my AppComponent HTML, I inject another component with
`<app-listpost></app-listpost>`

But in the TypeScript, I also receive this component because my AppComponent imports my ListPostComponent in order to call a function from ListPostComponent in AppComponent.

The function simply adds an object to an array from ListPostComponent

Thus, I found out that calling that function from AppComponent works but the array with which AppComponent works is from another instance than the array from the ListPostComponent instanciated with the HTML tag.

**app.component.html**

```html
<div style="text-align:center">
  <h1>
    {{ getTitle() }}
  </h1>
</div>
<app-listpost></app-listpost>
<button class="btn btn-success" (click)="addPostToList('test title from AppComponent', 'test content from AppComponent')">Add test post</button>
```

**app.component.ts**

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ListpostComponent } from './listpost/listpost.component'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
  providers:[ListpostComponent]
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'Exercise';

  constructor(private listPostComp: ListpostComponent){}

  public addPostToList(newTitle, newContent){
    this.listPostComp.addPostToList(newTitle, newContent);
  }

  getTitle(){
      return this.title;
  }
}
```

**listpost.component.html**

```html
<button class="btn btn-success btn-test" (click)="addPostToList('test title from ListPostComponent', 'test content from ListPostComponent')">Add test post</button>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <ul class="list-group">
                <app-post   *ngFor="let post of getListPosts()"
                            [Title]="post.title"
                            [Content]="post.content"></app-post>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**listpost.component.ts**

```js
import { Component, OnInit, ChangeDetectionStrategy } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-listpost',
  templateUrl: './listpost.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./listpost.component.scss'],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.Default
})
export class ListpostComponent implements OnInit {

    private listPosts = [
        {
            title: 'Post example',
            content: 'Content example'
        }
    ];

    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit() {
    }

    addPostToList(newTitle, newContent){
        let newPost = {
            title: newTitle,
            content: newContent
        }

        this.listPosts.push(newPost);

        console.log("Added new post with title : \"" + newTitle + "\" and content : \"" + newContent + "\"");
        console.log(this.listPosts); //DEBUG
    }

    getListPosts(){
        return this.listPosts;
    }
}
```

The ultimate goal was that cliking the button from **app.component.html** would call the function from **listpost.component.ts**, add an object to the array and that the display from **listpost.component.html** would refresh with the newly added object.

It works when I click the button in **listpost.component.html** but not from **app.component.html** for the reason I explained above.

Therefore, is there a way for me to specify that I want to use the instance of ListPostComponent I receive in the constructor of AppComponent in the HTML tag `<app-listpost></app-listpost>` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think best practice would be to create an injectable service that contains a function with your `addPostToList()` logic.  Then create another function in your `ListPostComponent` that calls that service function and updates the `listPosts`.  Then in your `AppComponent`, call the function from your `ListPostComponent`.